# Self directed RRSP - what are some good general guidelines on when to look at switching to one?

Tags: canada, rrsp, self-directed

My bank is trying to sell me on switching to using a self-directed RRSP account. Right now, it doesn't make sense to me to do it, but it does look like an interesting investment option.

What are some general guidelines I should be following for self-directed RRSPs? When should I start looking at switching into one, or, the reverse, switching out of using one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it strange that they would actually recommend switching to a SD RSP. Most of the Big 5 banks would be happy to have you blindly invested in their high-fee mutual funds without even making you aware that the self-directed option exists.

In my view, there are a few very important things to consider:

1. **Would you like your investments to be self-directed?** Would you be able to decide what to invest your money in if you had all the choice that's offered through a SD RSP? Would your financial advisor at the bank still be involved? Only consider answering the question of *when you should start looking into switching to one* if you have already decided that you *would like to switch to one*. If you would like to have a SD RSP, it might make sense once your invested amount can justify any added commissions and fees you may incur with your new investments. If it's at a Big 5 bank (i.e. TD or RBC) you're looking at $30/trade for stocks and ETFs, and maybe a fee for third-party mutual funds.
2. **Are you well-versed with all the products that you can invest in using a self-directed account?** Although I would generally recommend a SD RSP, or even a self-directed TFSA or non-registered account, it would behoove an investor to really be committed to knowing what they're doing. Without presuming too much about the OP, I would recommend anyone reading this answer to start at a great [post at the Financial Webring Forums](http://www.financialwebring.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=101652).
3. **What are all the fees associated with the SD RSP?** Many of the Big 5 banks and other companies charge exorbitant fees. Commission fees notwithstanding, the two major fees that I would be careful about are the *annual administration fees* and *transfer out fees*. RBC Direct Investing, for example, [charges](http://www.rbcdirectinvesting.com/RBC%3aTV3Q-Y71A8UAB1EAWM0/commissions-fees-schedule.html#registered) $75/yr for RSPs that are less than $25000 in value. They also charge an exorbitant $135 transfer out fee. Of course, you'd need to pay that if you decide to switch brokerages since you can't just withdraw from bank A and redeposit at bank B without triggering tax consequences.
4. **If you really would like a self-directed account, must you stick with your current bank?** Having said all this, I think that there are other brokerages out there that should be evaluated apart from the Big 5 banks should you choose to go this route, *particularly* if one has less than $25000 invested. A good starting point is at a [post at the Million Dollar Journey blog](http://www.milliondollarjourney.com/review-canadian-discount-brokerages.htm), which includes a table of many Canadian discount brokerages. The irony would be staggering if you inform your financial advisor at your bank that you have decided to take their advice and open a SD RSP, but somewhere else.

Best of success with your RRSP, whatever you decide to do. If you would like me to elaborate further on any of these points, please post a comment and I'll do what I can.